# "cannot" or "can not"? -- "As I am at the dentist. I obviously ____ sign for the package."

Tags: modal-verbs

In this exercise we have to complete the space with 4 potential correct answers:

> *As I am at the dentist. I obviously ____ sign for the package.*
>
> a) *cannot* b) *can not* c) *could not* d) *did*

I have chosen "can not" because of the present conjugation in this sentence. Because your English is better than mine, you might choose "cannot" and that's the reason I want to ask you this question. Why and how?

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between **cannot** and **can not** in written English is that the former is for negation only and the later has additional unusual meaning as the ability to not perform some action.

> I **cannot** tell a lie.  (*I am unable to tell a lie.*)
>   I **can not** tell a lie. (99% of the time = *I am unable to tell a lie.*  1% of the time = *I am able to not lie.*)

In spoken English, we almost always speak the two words as one, "cannot," regardless of how the words would be written.

In your example, either *cannot* or *can not* would be entirely appropriate, and nobody would look twice at it in either form.  If I had to choose, I would go with cannot, as it reads slightly more fluidly aloud, but that's a really minor distinction between the two forms.  They're almost exactly synonymous.

Comment: What is the difference between 'I am unable to tell a lie' and 'I am able to not lie'?

Comment: @RuchirM This may help: Professor: "Robot, can you lie?" Robot: "I'm unable to tell a lie. I'm unable to lie." Professor: "Haha! Let me tinker with your robot-brain!" (15 minutes passed) Professor: "I've reprogrammed you to be able to lie. Now, tell me a lie!" Robot: "But, sir. Because I'm still able to not lie, I choose not to lie to you." :-)

Comment: @RuchirM My example is far less sophisticated, but imagine a man and a woman talking.  Woman: "Men can't resist looking at every beautiful women they see."  Man: "That's absurd, I can not look at a beautiful woman."  This doesn't mean that he is unable to look at beautiful women, instead it means that he can control himself, he has the ability to not look.